# App icon is offscreen on iOS 13 devices and it cannot be pressed via XCUITest

Tags: ios13, ios-ui-automation, xcuitest

I am using the following method to delete my app from Springboard, yet it seems that once in a while its frame seems to be offscreen and therefore isHittable becomes false.

```
let springApp = XCUIApplication(bundleIdentifier: "com.apple.springboard")    
let icon = springApp.otherElements.icons["App Name"]
        if icon.exists {
            let iconFrame = icon.frame
            icon.press(forDuration: 3)

            springApp.tapAtPoint(iconFrame.origin)

            sleep(0.5)
            springApp.alerts.buttons["Delete"].tap()
```

Below is the provided position when the issue happens:

```
 ▿ (-2.0, -2.0, 4.0, 4.0)
  ▿ origin : (-2.0, -2.0)
    - x : -2.0
    - y : -2.0
  ▿ size : (4.0, 4.0)
    - width : 4.0
    - height : 4.0
```

Any idea why this happens and if I can somehow fix it? It doesn't seem to reproduce on iOS 12 devices though.

Comment: I have the same issue and I haven't find any solution yet... I tried to terminate the app before but same result...

Comment: I am having the same problem. Did someone found a fix for this issue?

Comment: Does it still fail with the last Xcode update ? Plus, during your test execution, do you switch to other apps ? I try to find ways to reproduce the failure.

Comment: I no longer reproduce the failure after upgrading to iOS 13.2.

Answer (score 1):

Springboard seems to return proper coordinates if resetting home screen layout:
Settings -> General -> Reset -> Reset Home Screen Layout.

Below you can find the solution that works for me without flakiness:

```
func resetHomeScreenLayout(file: String = #file, line: Int = #line) {
    settingsApp.launch()

    let settingsGeneralCell = settingsApp.cells["General"]
    XCTAssertTrue(settingsGeneralCell.waitForExistence(timeout: Constants.smallWaitTime),
                  "The \"General\" cell in Settings was not found. Error in file \(file) at line \(line).")
    settingsGeneralCell.tap()

    let settingsResetCell = settingsApp.cells["Reset"]
    XCTAssertTrue(settingsResetCell.waitForExistence(timeout: Constants.smallWaitTime),
                  "The \"Reset\" cell in Settings was not found. Error in file \(file) at line \(line).")
    settingsResetCell.tap()

    let settingsResetHomeScreenLayoutLink = settingsApp.staticTexts["Reset Home Screen Layout"]
    XCTAssertTrue(settingsResetHomeScreenLayoutLink.waitForExistence(timeout: Constants.smallWaitTime),
                  "The \"Settings\" link \"Reset Home Screen Layout\" was not found. Error in file \(file) at line \(line).")
    settingsResetHomeScreenLayoutLink.tap()

    let settingsResetHomeScreenPopOverButton = settingsApp.sheets.buttons["Reset Home Screen"]
    XCTAssertTrue(settingsResetHomeScreenPopOverButton.waitForExistence(timeout: Constants.smallWaitTime),
                  "The \"Settings\" popover \"Reset Home Screen\" button was not found. Error in file \(file) at line \(line).")
    settingsResetHomeScreenPopOverButton.tap()

    settingsApp.terminate()
}
```

Call this method before long pressing the app icon and it should be hittable.
Make sure to swipe left the springboard as needed for the app icon to become visible.
This works for me at least on iOS 13.1.3.

Comment: This feature is not available on simulators

Answer (score 0):

This works for me in all OS version(iOS11,12 & 13)

```
static let springboard = XCUIApplication(bundleIdentifier: "com.apple.springboard")

    func deleteApp() {
        XCUIApplication().terminate()
        springboard.activate()

        let icon = springboard.icons[appName]

        if icon.exists {
            icon.firstMatch.press(forDuration: 5)
            icon.buttons["DeleteButton"].tap()
            XCUIDevice.springboard.coordinate(withNormalizedOffset: CGVector(dx: (iconFrame.minX + 3) / springboardFrame.maxX, dy: (iconFrame.minY + 3) / springboardFrame.maxY)).tap()
            let deleteConfirmation = springboard.alerts["Delete “\(appName)”?"].buttons["Delete"]
            XCTAssertTrue(deleteConfirmation.waitForExistence(timeout: 5), "Delete confirmation not shown")
            deleteConfirmation.tap()
        }
    }
```